# Sorting questions/answers in user lists based on accepted status

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I would like the ability, in all SE sites, to sort the lists of questions and answers in a user's profile page primarily by whether that user's question has an accepted answer, or equivalently whether the user's answer was marked as the accepted answer.

It would probably be of value to be able to specify a secondary sort by one of the existing criteria, so this might be an "on/off" criteria that can be toggled. When "on", results are sorted first by this "acceptance status", then by the other specified criteria (votes/newest/activity)

Comment: I looked through all the "similar" questions and didn't find that. How embarrassing. However, that question mentions that integrating the feature into the UI would be better, even given the ability to search by accepted status.